# what's the proper way to declare static mutable values

Tags: c++, scope, static

I've got a mutable static value in my program.

```
static int foo = 0;
```

regardless of private or public accessibility I don't want nasty name collisions.
I don't like things just sitting in the scope of my namespace.
So I tried the following

```
class aClass{ 
    static int foo = 0;
}
```

Apperantly this is impossible, unless I don't assign a variable to `foo`.
Which is impossible for foo in my program.

What is the standard on declaring mutable statics with a default value?
I read something about people using `const <T>*` but that doesn't sound sane to me, and seems prone to error.

Comment: A global static variable and a static classvariable have two completely different meanings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about header:

```
class aClass {
  static int foo;
}
```

cpp file

```
int aClass::foo;
```

you can then add an initialisation if you want to there.

Comment: Perfect! Will accept your answer once the timer lets me.